# One-Liner for check if Optional is nil or not in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

How do I check if an optional variable in Swift is nil or not in one line to return a Bool?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
class UserManager  {

    var signedInUser: User? = nil

    // some code

    func isSignedIn() -> Bool {
        return self.signedInUser?
    }
}
```

This leads to the following error message:

> Cannot convert the expression's type '$T3??' to type 'Bool'

Also I have tried the following:

```
func isSignedIn() -> Bool {
    return self.signedInUser == nil
}
```

This lead to the very odd error message:

> Type 'UIStatusBarStyle' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

I don't want to do the following in the `isSignedIn` method as it is too long for this simple task:

```
func isSignedIn() -> Bool {
    if let signedInUser = self.signedInUser {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Am I missing something here? I though Swift makes code **shorter** and **simpler**. How would you do it?

Comment: I can't find the duplicate question but this is a bug in Beta 4. The simplest workaround is calling `.getLogicValue` or using it implicitly e.g. `if signedInUser {`.

Comment: @Sulthan: How do we know that the current behavior is the bug and not a feature? If it worked in previous betas this doesn't necessarily mean the current one is buggy. But thank you for the other thread. The `getLogicValue()` method helps!

Comment: @Dschee Because it has been confirmed on Apple Dev Forums, see https://devforums.apple.com/message/1000658#1000658

Comment: You can also use `!!self.signedUser` although this is a gross workaround for anybody who has never worked with Javascript.

Comment: I have just filed a bug report on this to ensure this is either fixed or at least cleared out somehow different. #17868980

Comment: @Sulthan: Thanks for the link! For the workaround: Please post it as an answer so I can vote it up. I think it's a funny workaround. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the ternary operator will do the trick.

```
func isSignedIn() -> Bool {
    return self.signedInUser ? true : false
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it actually does solve my problem with a one-liner although there might be a cleaner solution. But maybe it's due to the Beta status of the language/compiler that it doesn't work yet. Only time can tell.